# could not resolve hostname with ~/.ssh/config and aliases

Tags: ssh, linux-networking

I have a config file `~/.ssh/config` that looks something like this:

```sh
Host *.texas
  User john

Host *.texas !gateway.texas
  HostName %h.unitedstates.com
  ProxyJump gateway.texas

Host gateway.texas
  HostName ssh.texas.unitedstates.com

Host dallas austin
  HostName %h.texas
  RemoteCommand zsh -l
```

In summary, I expect that `ssh dallas` resolves to something like `ssh -J ssh.texas.unitedstates.com john@dallas.texas.unitedstates.com zsh -l` while `ssh houston.texas` resolves to `ssh -J john@ssh.texas.unitedstates.com john@houston.texas.unitedstates.com`. The second example works as expected but not the first one (unresolved hostname). I suspect that it has something to do with the `%h.texas` which should in turn be resolved as `%h.unitedstates.com`

Could anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: I could be wrong but I do not think that hostname resolution is supposed to work recursively.  Your first example requires *two* hostname resolutions cascaded; i.e., the second one needing to use the result of the first one as its argument.  (Your second example requires only one hostname resolution, and one proxyjump hostname resolution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, by default recursive hostname resolution is not possible, but several options can help, including Match and CanonicalDomains/CanonicalHostName. In the end, I turned the problem around with something like this:

```sh
CanonicalDomains texas.unitedstates.com
CanonicalizeFallbackLocal no
CanonicalizeHostname yes

Host *.texas.unitedstates.com
  User john
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/texas

Host *.texas.unitedstates.com !ssh.texas.unitedstates.com
  HostName %h
  ProxyJump ssh.texas.unitedstates.com

Host dallas austin
  HostName %h.texas.unitedstates.com
  RequestTTY yes
  RemoteCommand tmux new -As remote
```

More information on [Canonicalization](https://dotfiles.tnetconsulting.net/articles/2016/0109/ssh-canonicalization.html) and on [Match](https://dev.to/nabbisen/openssh-configurations-by-hosts-h1g).

Comment: oh this is wonderful; I did not even know about canonicalisation!  Thanks